# Out of bounds on the wrong variable with mktime

Tags: c, mktime

I am trying to add a user input date to an existing time struct but I am getting an error I do not understand. The complier is telling me the weekday is out of bounds when I am trying to modify the month date. Code is posted below.

```
struct tm date;
int m, d, y, n;
char buffer[80];
printf("Enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format.\n");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m, &d, &y);

date.tm_mday = d;
date.tm_mon = m;
date.tm_year = y - 1900;
mktime(&date);

printf("How many days would you like to advance this time?");
scanf("%d", &n);
date.tm_mday += n;
mktime(&date);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &date);
printf("Your new date is %c", buffer);
```

Comment: You know the month range is 0 to 11 right ? Given the december being 12th month..

Comment: What fields are *also* in the `struct tm date;` you declared that you never bothered setting to *any* determinate value? Some are ignored by `mktime`; some are not. Do you expect `mktime` to somehow *guess* those values were *not* set by you before the call?

Comment: Initialize all the elements of the `struct tm` to 0 before starting work: `struct tm date = { 0 };`.  At the moment you are using indeterminate values for the time components of the structure.  You should also check that the `scanf()` calls worked — returned the correct number of values (3 and 1 respectively).  You could test the calls to `mktime()`; you could print the `date` values after each call to `mktime()`.  Are you sure it is the compiler complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems

- `.tm_mon` expects the months *since* January 0-11.

  This usually means to subtract 1 from user's input.  [@dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584904/out-of-bounds-on-the-wrong-variable-with-mktime/53585015#comment94033332_53584904)

  ```
  // date.tm_mon = m;
  date.tm_mon = m - 1;
  ```

---

- `mktime(&date);` reads all members aside from `.tm_yday` and `.tm_wday` and OP's only sets 3 of them.  Best to initialize all members with `{0}` as we only known of 7 others and there *might* be more. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584904/out-of-bounds-on-the-wrong-variable-with-mktime/53585015#comment94033471_53584904)

---

- Code did not check the return value of `mktime()` for errors.

---

- Use `"%s"` to print a *string*.  This implies OP does not have a good compiler with warnings fully enable.  Save time and enable all warnings with a good compiler.

  ```
  char buffer[80];
  printf("Your new date is %c", buffer);  // Bad specifier
  ```

---

Put this all together.

```
// struct tm date;
struct tm date = {0}; // Initialize all
int m, d, y, n;
char buffer[80];

printf("Enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format.\n");
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m, &d, &y) != 3) {
  Handle_error();  
}


date.tm_mday = d;
// date.tm_mon = m;
date.tm_mon = m - 1;
date.tm_year = y - 1900;
date.tm_isdst = -1; // Set dst flag to: let mktime figure it out
if (mktime(&date) == -1) {
  Handle_error();  
}

printf("How many days would you like to advance this time?");
scanf("%d", &n);
date.tm_mday += n;
if (mktime(&date) == -1) {
  Handle_error();  
}

strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &date);
printf("Your new date is %s", buffer);
```